# CSS: image url doesn't work

Tags: css, image, url

Here is my folders structure:

```
- var/www/project
  - public
    - images
      - image1.png
    - style.css
  - storage
    - other_images
      - image2.png
```

I'm trying to access the picture with `background-image: url("../storage/other_images/image2.png");`

However the image is not displayed. But if I try to access another image like this: `background-image: url("/images/image1.png");` it works.

And if I try `background-image: url("../public/images/image1.png");` it fails again. Which should work as I'm basically providing the same url.

Another weird thing is that `background-image: url("../images/image1.png");` also works (should it?). I can even write `background-image: url("../../../../../../../images/image1.png");` and it still finds it.

Is this how it is supposed to be?

The main question is: how do I properly specify url for the image2.png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `public` and `storage` is in same level and `storage` becomes not accessible via URL, because it's not under web root.

Also `../somedir/image.png` will be interpreted from current directory. Better always specify `/somedir/image.png` (with first character `/` as it specifies root directory).

Comment: I remember url being relative to css file's location. So the solution is to move image2.png inside images/ ?

Comment: @Linas If your URL is not in CSS, but in image tag, than it may change. And yes, move all images to web accessible location